# How can I convert string type to List<PaintContent> in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

My paintContent class looks like this

```
abstract class PaintContent {
  PaintContent();

  PaintContent.paint(this.paint);

  late Paint paint;


  


  PaintContent copy();

  void draw(Canvas canvas, Size size, bool deeper);


  void drawing(Offset nowPoint);

  void startDraw(Offset startPoint);


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();




}
```

I'm saving with path provider and I couldn't convert the json value I read as a string to this type.

How can I do this save?

Comment: First of all, this only have Paint parameter inside the class. Why do you need to create Paint object from Json. 

Then, this is an abstract class. So you cannot make an instance with this.